# Is it possible to use objectify on android?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, objectify

I'm building android app and trying to leverage AppEngine backend. Is it possible to avoid using JPA and JDO and use objectify there? Thank you for any answers.

Comment: How would it make sense to use Objectify there? You don't have access to the datastore, you're just making remote calls to the backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Objectify on the App Engine backend, but not in the Android application where is would not make sense. You can still use the same classes in Android, even if they are annotated for Objectify.

Comment: Ah, ok, I thought about it but I wasn't sure. Thanks :)